# Ruby: Ideas to convert Arel.sql to Arel::Nodes::Case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I'm trying to refactor a piece of code (and to improve my understanding of `Arel::Nodes::Case` as well) and I would like to convert this `Arel.sql` statement

```ruby
    Arel.sql(default_order)
    def default_order
        "CASE
          WHEN applications.status = 'new' AND owner_id IS NULL THEN '1'
          WHEN applications.is_priority = '1' AND is_read = '0' AND owner_id = '#{current_user.id}'  THEN '2'
          WHEN applications.is_priority = '1' THEN '3'
          ELSE '4'
         END, applications.code"
    end
```

into an `Arel::Nodes::Case` but I'm not getting any good result. Any ideas that could help?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I did this approach, but I don't like it at all. Too difficult to read and understand:

```ruby
  def default_order
    arel_applications = Application.arel_table
    Arel::Nodes::Case.new
        .when((arel_applications[:status].eq('new'))
                  .and(arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(nil)), 1)
        .when((arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1))
                  .and(arel_applications[:is_read].eq(0))
                  .and(arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(current_user.id)), 2)
        .when(arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1), 3)
        .else(4).to_sql
  end
```

Even so, I'm not sure how to get that `applications.code` that is used in the SQL to order the records.

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60413416/493321

Comment: Thanks Anuj, I tried something similar to that but I don't like what I got. I'm going to update my post with the approach that I got.

It's too difficult and ugly to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot always expect `Arel` to be pretty. `Arel` is a very complex and flexible query assembler and a side effect of this complexity is often verbosity.

That being said using `Arel` over raw sql is always preferential in my opinion because it is sanitary, dynamic, and database agnostic.

We can alter your update to be a bit more readable by utilizing the `then` method rather than a second argument to `when`. This will cause the code to read a lot more like a CASE statement such as `.when(condition).then(value)`.

The alteration would look like this:

```
  def default_order
    arel_applications = Application.arel_table
    case_stmnt = Arel::Nodes::Case.new
        .when(arel_applications[:status].eq('new').and(
                 arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(nil)
             )
          ).then(1)
        .when(arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1).and(
                arel_applications[:is_read].eq(0).and(
                  arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(current_user.id)
                )
              )
          ).then(2)
        .when(arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1)
          ).then(3)
        .else(4)
  end
```

Now to deal with the second part of the question *"Even so, I'm not sure how to get that applications.code that is used in the SQL to order the records."*

we can use `Arel::Nodes::Grouping` to handle this:

```
def default_order
    arel_applications = Application.arel_table
    case_stmnt = Arel::Nodes::Case.new
        .when(arel_applications[:status].eq('new').and(
                 arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(nil)
             )
           ).then(1).
        .when(arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1).and(
                arel_applications[:is_read].eq(0).and(
                  arel_applications[:owner_id].eq(current_user.id)
                )
              )
          ).then(2)
        .when(arel_applications[:is_priority].eq(1)
          ).then(3)
        .else(4)
    Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(case_stmnt,arel_applications[:code])
  end
```

This will result in the following SQL:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN [applications].[status] = N'new' AND [applications].[owner_id] IS NULL THEN 1 
  WHEN [applications].[is_priority] = 1 AND [applications].[is_read] = 0 AND [applications].[owner_id] = 1 THEN 2 
  WHEN [applications].[is_priority] = 1 THEN 3 
  ELSE 4 END, 
[applications].[code])
```

Then you can just use this as an argument to `order` (no need to convert `to_sql` as rails will take care of this for you e.g. `Application.order(default_order)`

You can also append sort direction to both the `case_stmnt` and the `arel_applications[:code]` column e.g. `case_stmnt.asc` or `case_stmnt.desc`

Comment: Thank you very much @engineersmnky, pretty clear.