# Sum same column as total sum, and also partial sums from that same column based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a schema that looks like this:

Purchase belongs to OrderItem, and OrderItem belongs to an Order.  The purchase belongs to order through order_items.

The purchase has a column called amount, and orders have a column called gateway transaction id.  When orders have a gateway_transaction_id, the purchase is considered to be online.  And when the orders do not have a gateway_transaction_id, the purchase is considered to be offline.

Currently, I have a need to do total_sum of purchases, total_sum of online purchases, and total_sum of offline purchases.

Here is what I have currently:

```
all_active_purchases.joins(:order).selecting {
          [
            sum(amount).as('total_purchase_amount'),
            count(id).as('total_purchases_count'),
            count(distinct(purchaser_id)).as('total_purchaser_count')
          ]
```

This is done using baby_squeel gem.

I can add an online and offline scope on donations as such:

```
scope :online -> { joins(:order).where.not(orders: {gateway_transaction_id: nil})
scope :offline -> { joins(:order).where(orders: {gateway_transaction_id: nil})
```

Then I can just get the other two sums as:

```
purchases.online.sum(:amount)
purchases.offline.sum(:amount)
```

But it feels unnecessary to have the last two queries.  I would like to calculate all values as part of the first query of calculating total_purchase_amount to reduce the number of database queries.  Is it possible to calculate all this as part of one query? I'm going to tag mysql tag as well as I can use mysql syntax as well in the application.

Here is the relevant schema:

```
create_table "purchases", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal "amount", precision: 10, scale: 2, null: false
    t.integer "purchaser_id", null: false
end
create_table "order_items", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "order_id"
    t.string "item_type"
    t.integer "item_id"
end
create_table "orders", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "gateway_transaction_id"
end
```

Example data:

```
Purchases:
id: 1, amount: 20
id: 2, amount: 30
order_items:
id: 1, item_type: "Purchase", item_id: 1, order_id: 1
id: 2, item_type: "Purchase", item_id: 2, order_id: 2
order:
id: 1, gateway_transaction_id: 'abcdef'
id: 2, gateway_transaction_id:
```

Above purchase with id 1 would be online purchase as its order has a gateway transaction id, while purchase with id 2 would be offline as its order as nil gateway_transaction_id

Comment: Can you add the schema of the table, example data and expected output?

Comment: purchases table: 
amount (decimal)
order_item_id (integer, foreign_key);

order_items (table)
order_id (integer, foreign key);
id

orders (table)
id (integer)
gateway_transaction_id (string)

@SebastianPalma

Comment: You can get the schema from your db/schema.rb file (or db/structure.sql). Still no example data and expected output, I (we) don't see the same you see, nor we know the same you know. For helping you we have to first understand better what you have and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks, I've added schema and sample data.

Comment: What's the relationship between the purchases table and the others? I see your scopes have access to the orders, but don't see their relationships stated.

Comment: @SebastianPalma
Purchase
    has_one :order_item, as: :item, dependent: :destroy;
    has_one :order, through: :order_item;

Order has many order_items, and order_item belongs to order.  ;
And order_item also has:
belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` together with a `CASE` statement to get a "filted" aggregeate:

```
all_active_purchases.joins(:orders)
        .select(
           'SUM(CASE WHEN orders.gateway_transaction_id IS NULL THEN purchases.amount ELSE 0 END) AS offline_amount',
           'SUM(CASE WHEN orders.gateway_transaction_id IS NOT NULL THEN purchases.amount ELSE 0 END) AS online_amount'
        )
```

Comment: I don't really know squeel well enough to translate this so I leave that up to you. You might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411301/case-statements-in-arel